# chaotic multithreading in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-sleep

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView view;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
        view.setText("how are you");

        handler.post(r);

        System.out.println("oncreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        System.out.println("onstart");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
}
```

In the **activity_main.xml**, I adopt the LinearLayout,and there is only one TextView in it.After running the program, the text string "how are you" will display on the screen in 10 seconds later. But the text string "oncreate" and "onstart" can display in the logcat instantly. How could this happen? In my opinion, all of text strings should be displayed in 10 seconds later after running the program.

Comment: You should call Thread.sleep in the main thread, if you want to stop some GUI work, now it is a separate Thread.

Comment: If you want this to do in Android only then you may go for `Looper` that basically gives you power of executing threads in sequence.

Comment: maybe the gui renders after onCreate(),
so the variables are set after: `view.setText("how are you");`
but not rendered. Then the Handler calls r in his own thread, taht causes the gui-thread not to stop.

But I don't know why the rendering will start 10 seconds later

Comment: @Demonick,I tried as you suggested, all of strings displayed in 10s later after running the program.But I am wondering why the program above can't have the same effect.Now that "how are you "delays for 10s, the "oncreate" and "onstart" should also delay for 10s.

Comment: it might be quiet helpful to view the call-hierarchy diagram:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: @coqer why should they delay . As you are using threads , which are different processes.

Comment: I think the rendering thread is bound to the message-queue of Handler.
So after the rendering is finished, the handler is next

Comment: @cIph3r, I can't agree with you, "oncreate" and "onstart" will display  at the same time, this means the program has already entered into the onStart().As for why 10s, I called Thread.sleep(10000) in the Runnalbe!

Comment: @coqer No: "When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it"
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

That means the runnable runs in its own thread, making the activity initalizing asyncronously. But the handler has the message-queue of the gui-thread

Comment: When a process is created for your application, its main thread is dedicated to running a message queue that takes care of managing the top-level application objects (activities, broadcast receivers, etc) and any windows they create. You can create your own threads, and communicate back with the main application thread through a Handler. This is done by calling the same post or sendMessage methods as before, but from your new thread. The given Runnable or Message will then be scheduled in the Handler's message queue and processed when appropri

Comment: "The given Runnable or Message will then be scheduled in the Handler's message queue and processed when appropriate."
Meaning the sleep is queued in the gui-thread. After the gui is rendered, the Handler with the sleep-code is activated.

Comment: But the question is: What do you wanna do here exactly?
Then we can provide answers

Answer (score 0):

The simply way to do it is there:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
System.out.println("oncreate");
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
}).start();
    view.setText("how are you");

}
```

This code will print the "onstart" and "oncreate" on logcat inmediately, 10 secs next will set the text on the textview...